# chrome wont let me access localhost (it google searches instead)

Tags: google-chrome

How can I disable chrome using address bar for google search?

I cant access localhost at 0.0.0.0:6000, because chrome thinks it's a google search and not an url

any ideas?

Comment: doesnt work, i also need to specifiy port

Comment: Chrome will accept `http://localhost:6000`, if it doesnt then you are not typing it correctly.

Comment: I need to use 0.0.0.0 not localhost

Answer (score 8):

This may be because a url was added to your search history.  Google is doing you a favor because that's what you did once before somehow.

Try clearing your history to see if this is the case.

[image]

I went to "Clear Browsing Data" in Settings > Advanced and I was able to enter a localhost url again.

Comment: what this was done a few months ago and doesn't appear in the history?

Answer (score 7):

Be sure you end the url with "/" symbol.

Try:

http://0.0.0.0:6000/

Instead of:

0.0.0.0:6000

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me (Chrome 69.0.3497.100)

Answer (score 3):

SOLUTION For chrome version 62:

settings > advanced > Use a web service to help resolve navigation errors > OFF

Comment: Turning off this setting does not seem to solve the issue in Chorme 69.0.3497.100

Answer (score 0):

Try
- turn off Search Suggestions
- under LAN settings, uncheck "use automatic configuration"

Do you get the same behavior with an incognito window?

Comment: Also found another solution to share please go to chrome://flags and set "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" to "Disabled", then restart the browser and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this alternative: `http://127.1.1.1:6000` or `127.1.1.1:6000` (without http).

Answer (score 0):

A search through the web has revealed several different possible causes to this problem as well as solutions.

Causes:

1. this is malware
2. this is a chrome/browser issue
3. this is a misconfiguration of the httpd service

Solutions:

1. scan for malware, though probably not the issue.
2. update the host file, so that localhost points to 127.0.0.1
3. confirm your httpd service is accepting http:// requests through port 80, 8080, or some other port.
4. make sure the URL has the correct port .. http://localhost:8080
5. try appending different delimiting characters [ / ? # ] to the URL ...

   localhost/Dir/

   localhost/Dir?p=x

   localhost/Dir#123
6. does it happen on a specific directory?

   localhost/Dir .. works

   localhost/Dir2 .. goes to search.

This suggests that the httpd service's configuration may need to be fixed.  or that an .htaccess file is the cause.  If these problems can be ruled out, then it's a browser issue.

7. remove the autocomplete entry from the browsers search/address bar

   in most cases, type the url, using the arrow keys - highlight the offending entry, press [DELETE] or [SHIFT}+[DELETE].
8. does your browser support turning off autocomplete or searching from the address bar?

   .. chrome .. [Disable Predictive Text](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-turn-off-address-bar-search-predictions-in-every-1758276767)

   .. firefox .. [Disable Predictive Text](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-popular-search-suggestions-firefox-search-bar?e=sph&redirectlocale=en-US&as=s&s=search&r=0&redirectslug=Search%20suggestions)
9. open the CLI and issue [ >wget localhost/dir ]. Observe what is returned on a working vs non working directory.

Follow up:

This issue is especially annoying when working with .htaccess files and browser redirect statements in PHP, ASP, nodeJS, and JSP which redirect the browser to a specific URL, but instead takes the user to a search page.  If at all possible pre-pend http:// and post-pend a slash (/) after the URL in redirects.

```
http://localhost/dir/
```

And, YES ... it is annoying to have to add extra characters (as a work around) to get URLs to work right.

Comment: this almost definitely is NOT malware, but all your other points are really good!

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late to the party here but I just encountered this same problem on the current chrome (v. 96.0.4664.93) and could it would not resolve any local address using any of the other methods that I found on the web(http://192.168.178.1 or setting flags or insecure DNS).

What solved the problem, was a simple "/" at the beginning of the query string.

Whenever I enter

`/192.168.178.1`

into the Omnibox and hit enter it works for all services.

If some other people could verify this - I'd be really happy to get some feedback on this approach.

Answer (score -1):

I have this problem often myself. First, go to just localhost, chrome should understand that, then, when you type in localhost/my/url/here, the context will allow chrome to understand to treat it as a url.