# localhost:3000/home.html opens google search in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, url, webpack, gulp

Whenever i open `localhost:3000/home.html` in chrome, chrome does not recognize it as URL, instead as a search term.

`localhost:3000/home.html#` works without issues. 
`localhost:3000/projects.html` works as well. (And any other URL)

What causes this? Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: It's a long shot, but can you check \ect\hosts file and see `localhost:3000/home.html` is in the list?

Comment: This answer solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52487944/2924547. It seems like an issue with Chrome dealing with history entries.

Answer (score 3):

i dont have such issue but can you try with http://

(EX: http://localhost:3000/#/)