# Unable to reach localhost from Chrome, after having installed Rancher desktop on Windows 10

Tags: google-chrome, networking, rancher-desktop

After having installed Rancher desktop on my Windows 10 laptop, I cannot reach services listening on localhost through Chrome. Rancher desktop is configured to support Moby/dockerd.

The error reported by Chrome is:

```
This site can’t be reached
The connection was reset.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` they are reachable, instead.

Ping resolves localhost to 127.0.0.1 correctly:

```
PS C:\> ping localhost

Pinging xxxxxxxxxx [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
PS C:\>
```

I noticed that the `hosts` file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) contains the following entry:

```
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

I tried to add

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

to the hosts file, unsuccessfully.

I tried to run the following:

```
netsh winsock reset
netsh int ip reset
ipconfig /release
ip/config /renew
ipconfig /flushdns
```

and to restart the pc, but it didn't work, either.

I also tried solutions to similar problems, like:

- [Localhost not working in Chrome, 127.0.0.1 does work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33524826/1288109)
- [chrome wont let me access localhost (it google searches instead)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050978/chrome-wont-let-me-access-localhost-it-google-searches-instead)

Any suggestion to solve the problem?